# Where can I find where an app is being used?

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection, app, 2019

Searched and searched and can't find the answer.  There is an app that's causing an error in my site collection.  But I don't remember where this app is being used. I want to find the app to delete it from my site. Is there a way to find where the app is being used in my site collection and delete it?

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: @Mike2500 "Remove PowerView app" is the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below powershell script that will allow you to quickly identify on what site an app is installed, and what version of it is installed

```
$appTitle = Read-Host "What is your App's title?"

$rootUrl = Read-Host "What is your Web Application's Root Url?"

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $rootUrl

foreach($site in $webApp.Sites)

{

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)

    {

        $appInstance = Get-SPAppInstance -Web $web.Url | Where{$_.Title -eq $appTitle}

        if($appInstance -ne $null)

        {

            Write-Host $web.Url -BackgroundColor Green

            Write-Host $appInstance.App.VersionString -BackgroundColor Cyan

        }

    }

}
```